# UIWebView & ShouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I have set up an app that uses a UIWebView. The UIWebView is used to display text formatted with CSS. In the text are links (a href=...). The format of the href is like this: tags.tagname

When a user clicks a link, I'd like to intercept the request and use loadHTMLString based on the contents of the HREF.

I have successfully parsed the URL, but I'm stymied on how to tell the webview to not load the requested href and load the string I want instead.

I've tried the following within ShouldStartLoadWithRequest:

```
genHTML=[self genTagPage:parsedString]; // a string declared earlier
[self.noteHTML loadHTMLString:genHTML baseURL:nil];
return NO;
```

But when the code is executed, I receive the following error:

```
2011-04-19 22:39:21.088 TestApp[27026:207] *** -[_PFArray release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xaa3cf40
```

genHTML is getting populated with the right data, so I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to prevent the default action for the link like the following:

```
<a href="somewhere.html" onClick="doSomething(); return false">
```

Check out [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html) for more details.

**Edit:**
Re-read your original code, and it would seem you've got an infinite loop going on.  shouldStartLoadWithRequest gets called once when they click on the link, then infinitely on your loadHTMLString line.  Making the call conditional on the navigationType should fix your problem:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        genHTML=[self genTagPage:parsedString]; // a string declared earlier
        [self.noteHTML loadHTMLString:genHTML baseURL:nil];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: No.. I need the click to happen, and for IOS to fire an event. That way, I know the link has been clicked and I can then parse out what the link is asking for and compute and present the requested information. I just dont want the original link to load - it wont - there's nothing there. It's a descriptor for what's really needed.

Comment: @Chris check my updated answer, I think that ought to sort you out.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't work out how to deal with the navigation type properly and this example help me resolve the infinite loop I was in.